# Parabolic elements of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: conic-sections, hyperbolic-geometry

The elements of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ are classified in elliptic, parabolic and hyperbolic elements.

It seems to me that elliptic elements preserve an ellipse and hyperbolic elements preserve a hyperbola, and I've thought those names came from that.

However, I realized that parabolic elements don't preserve any parabola.

Then, where do those names come from ?

Comment: See the explanation at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R)), "Classification of Elements".

Comment: Here's the [more specific wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R)#Classification_of_elements).

Comment: Thank you, but my question comes precisely from that wikipedia page ^^
Then it's just an analogy between the eccentricity and the trace, and there is no further geometric interpretation ?

Comment: I also saw the MO post, but they explain that the name "parabolic subgroup" comes from "parabolic elements", and not the origin of the name "parabolic elements".

Comment: It's a pretty strong analogy, but I think that's about all it is.

Comment: We've learned a lot about ellipses, parabolas, and hyperbolas since those names were coined oh so many centuries ago...

Comment: $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ is related to the isometries of the hyperbolic plane, or equivalently, the isometries $SO^+(2,1)$ of the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=-1$. These are classified into elliptic, parabolic, and hyperbolic types, and they do preserve exactly such curves on the hyperboloid surface.

Comment: @mr_e_man: Your comment should be an answer to the question.